# Passing in batch file with parameters as parameter in sftp command

Tags: batch-file, parameters, command, sftp

I am attempting to automate a upload/download from a sftp depot. The password is piped into the `sftp` command. I want the batch to execute as follows:

`batch1.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET usernameHost=%1
SET password=%2
SET inputLoc=%3
SET outputLoc=%4

(echo %2) | sftp -b (batch2.bat %3 %4) %1
```

A `batch2.bat` will have a put/get command so it needs the `inputLoc` and `outputLoc` parameters. Unfortunately the parenthesis do not apply, so I do not know how to pass `batch2.bat` any parameters without confusing the `sftp` command in this line.

Does anyone know how to do this or can suggest an alternative?

Here is the `sftp` command documentation: http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp

I am using Windows with the GOW Tools cmd extension.

Comment: FTP can usually take its own commands. What does batch2.bat do? Show us the code for that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `batch2.bat` produces an `sftp` script (`put`, etc), right? So you want its output to be stored to a temp file (named pipe) and its name used as an argument to the `sftp -b`.

Your syntax would be wrong even on *nix. It should be:

```
sftp -b <(batch2.bat %3 %4) %1
```

Note the `<`.

---

Anyway, this (process substitution) is not possible on Windows.

You have to use a temporary file:

```
call batch2.bat %3 %4 > sftp.txt
echo %2 | sftp -b sftp.txt %1
del sftp.txt
```

---

But note that in [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) (as of version 0.8.0) the `sftp` is just an alias to outdated [`psftp`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html) (version 0.63).

The `sftp` in Gow is a batch file that looks like:

```
@echo off
psftp %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

You should use the [official up-to-date release of the `psftp`](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) instead.

Also the `psftp` cannot read a password from a redirected input (the *nix `sftp` cannot either).

You can use the `-pw` switch instead:

```
psftp -b sftp.txt -pw %2 %1
```

(Note that the *nix `sftp` does not have the `-pw` switch)

---

Or use a Windows command-line SFTP client that can take commands on command-line, to avoid all the hacks that you try to use.

For example with [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET inputLoc=%3
SET outputLoc=%4

winscp.com /command ^
    "open sftp://user:password@host/" ^
    "put ""%inputLoc%"" ""%outputLoc%""" ^
    "exit"
```

(Note that in WinSCP you specify the password together with the username and hostname in the [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url), so I could not use your current `%1` and `%2` arguments directly)

For an introduction to WinSCP scripting, see:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

Note that no matter, what client you end up using, you have to deal somehow with a host key verification.

See how to [verify the host key in WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey).